# Delete UILabel from Storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

How can I remove a UILabel from storyboard in XCode? I mention that I use UIKit framework.

I'm looking for a "delete" button but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You should click the label and then use the keyboard's [Backspace] button. It's above the [Enter] button.

Comment: On all modern Apple keyboards, it's labeled “delete”, not “backspace”, and on [ANSI keyboard layouts](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201794) it's two rows above the “return” key.

Comment: You are right. My answer was based on the keyboard I use which looks like https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7471367

Answer (score 0):

Select the button in the canvas view or in the document outline. Then press the delete key on your keyboard or, from the menu bar, choose Edit > Delete.